# Generic string array where each of the items is of the array values union type

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the function argument type for an array of strings as options:

```
function (values: ("option1" | "option2" | "option3")[]) {
    ....
}
```

I am after a generic type where the function could receive this:

```
function (values: ("option1" | "option2")[]) {
    ....
}
```

And this:

```
function (values: ("option1" | "option2" | "option3" | "option4" | "option5")[]) {
    ....
}
```

What would be the type for a generic string array that holds a type that is the union type of any of its values?
Asked in different way, the type so that the function could receive any string array with each of its items being of the union type of any of the items of the array?

Comment: I'd really like to see a real [mcve] here that shows some actual uses including some code-based criterion for success.  Like, it's obvious you don't want `(values: string[]) => void`, but there's nothing here that shows why you don't want it, or what breaks if you try to use it.  If all you're asking for is "how do you get the union of elements of an array type", as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67426775/2887218) by @AlexWayne, then it doesn't seem motivated by the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow you here, but I believe you are after `SomeArray[number]`. Since arrays have numeric indices, indexing an array by `number` returns a union of all its values.

```
type MyArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']
type MyUnion = MyArray[number] // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, in my case, base on your advice I did the union with `type OptionUnionType = string[][number]`. Then I made an array of elements type, allowing anly the array elements with `type OptionUnionTypeArray = OptionUnionType[]`. I think I am overthinking this a bit, but it works. The purpose is to allow only the array element values in the type, kind of an enum behaviour

Comment: it does not make much sense unless you are manipulating the array elements a lot, and want to prevent something strange in the code while using those types, because if not, its clear that when you create an array and fill it in, the elements are of the array element type by default. Nevermind